# Passing array into URLSearchParams while consuming http call for get request

Tags: javascript

Going through the WebAPI documentation for [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), I didn't find any documentation on passing array as an parameter.

Can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

In fact, you can't pass an array directly but you can use several times the `append` method:

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('arrayparams', 'val1');
params.append('arrayparams', 'val2');
params.append('arrayparams', 'val3');
console.log(params.toString());
```

Comment: hmm, but I get `arrayparams=val1&arrayparams=val2&arrayparams=val3`, doesn't this supposed to give sth like `arrayparams=[val1,val2,val3]`

Comment: No, by specification, multiple instance of the same key is automatically an array.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Note that you need to use `params.getAll('arrayparams')` in order to extract the array back out (for those accessing the parameter client side).

Comment: PHP does not see multiple instance of the same key as an array

Comment: does not work as i write this answer in neither chrome nor ff

Comment: Oneliner: `[].reduce((acc, cur) => { acc.append('arrayparams', cur); return acc; }, new URLSearchParams()).toString()`

Comment: simpler and short URL option: (I added an answer with this example)


`const url = new URL('http://localhost/')
url.searchParams.append('date[0]', date1)
url.searchParams.append('date[1]', date2)
console.log(url.toString())`

Comment: If its not working for you, you might need to add brackets to the key.
`params.append('arrayparams[]', 'val1');`

Comment: when I pass string it gets converted to %27, is there any way we can resolve that? const arr = [
  {
    Id: 'a',
    value: '1',
    type:'string'
  },
  {
    Id: 'b',
    value: 2,
    type:'integer'
  },
];

var search = new URLSearchParams(arr.map(s=>[`${s.Id}`,(s.type === 'string'? `'${s.value}'` : s.value)]))
var searchString = search.toString()

console.log(searchString);

Comment: Didn't work for me, had to use `data.append('tags[]', tags[i]);` (note the `[]` part)

Comment: This answer is incorrect and misleading - you totally CAN pass arrays. `new URLSearchParams([["x",1], ["x",2], ["x",3]]).toString()` outputs "x=1&x=2&x=3". This answer makes it sound like you gotta call `.append` for every param, but you really don't - the normal approach when you want unique params would be to pass an object. `new URLSearchParams({a:1, b:2}).toString()`

Answer (score 30):

URLSearchParams can be passed a sequence of pairs, so to have an array of values:

```js
var ids = [1,2,3,4]
var search = new URLSearchParams(ids.map(s=>['id',s]))
var searchString = search.toString()
// "id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4"
```

```js
// To get the ids from the URL search string
var search_ids = [...search.getAll('id')]
```

Comment: Nice way to go, but you need to remove the `toString()` from `search`.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use @washington-braga's approach but don't want to install lodash:

```js
function buildParams(data) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams()

    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            value.forEach(value => params.append(key, value.toString()))
        } else {
            params.append(key, value.toString())
        }
    });

    return params.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In fact this is the simplest functional way:

```
const url = new URL('http://localhost/')
url.searchParams.append('date[0]', date1)
url.searchParams.append('date[1]', date2)
console.log(url.toString())
```

For sure you can iterate through an array.

Comment: Example URL outout  after you run `decodeURIComponent` on the string: `http://localhost/?date[0]=1662178968266&date[1]=1662178968266'`

I prefer @thierry-templier's response since its more in line with browser's default behavior / spec. To have it be similar to @thierry-templier's answer all you need to do is remove the square brackets from the `date` string above.
The browser allows multiple instance of the same key in the URL - this automatically represents  an array

Answer (score 4):

I've used Lodash `map` to iterate over objects/arrays and append the params dynamically.

```js
const buildParams = (data) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();

  map(data, (value, key) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
      map(value, item => params.append(key, item));
    } else {
      params.append(key, value);
    }
  });

  return params;
};

const params = {
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  bar: 'xyz'
}

const doFetch = fetch(`http://api.com/search?${buildParams(params)}`)
```

So the final URL will look like: `http://api.com/search?foo=a&foo=b&foo=c&bar=xyz`

Answer (score 3):

An array of key/value pair arrays should work:

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams([['params', 'v1'], ['params', 'v2']]).toString();
console.log(params);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
makeSearchParams(link) {
    var url = new URL(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + link);
    const params = this.getSearchParams();

    for (let key in params) {
        if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
            for (let key1 in params[key]) {
                url.searchParams.append(key + '[]', params[key][key1]);
            }
        } else {
            url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]);
        }

        return url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const buildParams = (search) => {
  if (!search) return "";

  const params = new URLSearchParams();

  Object.entries(search).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) params.append(key, value.join(","));
    else params.append(key, value.toString());
  });

  return `?${params}`;
};

const search = {
  types: ['good', 'bad', 'normal'],
  id: 777
}

const url = `http://good.com/${buildParams(search)}`;
```

As a result, you will get `http://good.com/?types=good,bad,normal&id=777`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that automatically appends array values as multiple entries/keys in the query string.

The difference to other solutions posted already is, that it is simpler to read and only considers arrays - without appending all other object keys again.

```js
function convertToQueryUrl(obj: never): string {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(obj);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            params.delete(key);
            value.forEach((v) => params.append(key, v));
        }
    }
    return params.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple reduce you can obtain this natively without installing any third party module

```js
function serializeParams<T extends object>(params: T): string {
    return Object.entries(params)
        .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
            if (Array.isArray(v)) {
                for (const val of v) {
                    acc.append(k, val);
                }

                return acc;
            }

            acc.append(k, v);

            return acc;
        }, new URLSearchParams())
        .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const objectToQuery = (field, obj, prefix = null) => {
    let query = "";
    if (obj) {
        let keys = Object.keys(obj);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                obj[key].forEach((e) => {
                    query += "&" + field + (prefix ?? "") + "[" + key + "]" + "[]=" + e;
                });
            } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
                query += objectToQuery(field, obj[key], (prefix ?? "") + "[" + key + "]");
            } else {
                query += "&" + field + (prefix ?? "") + "[" + key + "]=" + obj[key];
            }
        });
    }
    return query;
};
```

this will convert even complex objects to query e.g

```
const filter = {
  name:'sample',
  status:['open','closed'],
  attributes:{
    color:['red','blue'], 
    misc:{
      other:'someval'
    }
  }
}
const baseURL = 'http://localhost'
const query = baseURL+'?page=1'+ objectToQuery('filter',filter)
//http://localhost?page=1&filter[name]=sample
//&filter[status][]=open
//&filter[status][]=closed
//&filter[attributes][color][]=red
//&filter[attributes][color][]=blue
//&filter[attributes][misc][other]=someval
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it by itself, but you can use `forEach` or a loop to pass it:

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams();
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 'etc'].forEach(item => params.append("primes", item));
console.log(params.toString());
```

Or, you can even polyfill this:

```js
    URLSearchParams.prototype.appendArray = function(array) {
        [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 'etc'].forEach(item => this.append("primes", item))
    }
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.appendArray([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 'etc']);
    console.log(params.toString());
```

You see, I added an `appendArray` `function` to the `URLSearchParams` prototype, so from now on any object instantiated as a `URLSearchParams` object will have an `appendArray` `function` that expects an array and add `append` it. But, if you polyfill, make sure you polyfill before you are to use the method... :)

Answer (score -1):

The top answers had me thinking you couldn't pass multiple params at once, and that you had to resort to calling `.append()` once per param

That's not the case. You can pass an object with keys and values.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({name:"Phil Collins",age:72,role:"musician"});
console.log(params.toString());
```

Output: `name=Phil+Collins&age=72&role=musician`

Or you can pass an array of keyvaluepair-arrays

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams([["name","Phil Collins"], ["age",72], ["role","musician"]]);
console.log(params.toString());
```

Comment: This point misses the OP request about a single parameter being defined multiple times (an array).  But yes, you can define singular properties as a single object then use `append` for the array property only.