# How to replace querystring.stringify with URLSearchParams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deprecated

```js
querystring.stringify({
    error: 'error_status'
})
```

`querystring` is deprecated, how would I replace it with the native `URLSearchParams` here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  error: 'error_status'
});

console.log(params.toString());
// error=error_status

console.log(`?${params.toString()}`);
// ?error=error_status
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

---

Here's another example demonstrating how array values are handled:

```js
let arrayParams = new URLSearchParams({
    category: ['cat', 'dog']
});

arrayParams.append('tag', 'cat');
arrayParams.append('tag', 'dog');

console.log(arrayParams.toString());
// category=cat%2Cdog&tag=cat&tag=dog

console.log(decodeURIComponent('cat%2Cdog'))
// cat,dog
```

Comment: This may result different outputs in case of passing arrays as params. `querysyring.stringify({key: ['value1',  'value2']})` will be `key=value1&key=value2`, where as `new URLSearchParams({key: ['value1',  'value2']}).toString()` will be `key=value1%2Cvalue2` where `%2C` is encoded `,`. For array parameters you can refer this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797509/passing-array-into-urlsearchparams-while-consuming-http-call-for-get-request